# react native ios build succeeds but path to app bundle is wrong

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

When I run react-native run-ios build succeeds and created build folder under ios. But after build, when installation starts, get the below error. The project runs successfully when I run it through xcode. What I observed is that path beginning 'DerivedData' is wrong. Instead it should be 'build'. When I rename my 'build' folder to 'DerivedData' and re-run 'react-native run-ios' the whole process completes successfully but of course with the previous build.

How can I change the 'DerivedData' to 'build'?

This error occurred immediately after I upgraded from 0.59.9 to 0.60.0.

**Error:**
info Installing "DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobileappname.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
error Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobileappname.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobileappname.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnSimulator (/Users/armaneker/WebstormProjects/mobileappname/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:189:45)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

**React Native version:**
System:
OS: macOS 10.15
Binaries:
Node: 10.15.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
npm: 6.13.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.0, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0
Xcode: 11.0/11A420a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
react-native: 0.60.0 => 0.60.0
npmGlobalPackages:
create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7

**Steps To Reproduce**

- used rn-diff-purge to upgrade from 0.59.9 to 0.60.0
- android worked correctly
- react-native run-ios build succeeded but installation of
  app failed

Comment: Go to XCode > File > Workspace Settings.. . In the popup there's an `Advanced` button and above that there's a path to your DerivedData folder. You can click on the small arrow and navigate to the folder. Try to delete you DerivedData and see if your problem is fixed.

Comment: The settings are pointing to the correct location. There is no 'DerivedData' definition anywhere... Everything pointing to 'build' etc.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is not obvious, `react-native-cli` is trying to guess what xcode build configuration is currently setup on your computer which is what is happening on the function `getBuildPath()`

```js
function getBuildPath(configuration, appName, isDevice, scheme) {
  let device;

  if (isDevice) {
    device = 'iphoneos';
  } else if (appName.toLowerCase().includes('tvos')) {
    device = 'appletvsimulator';
  } else {
    device = 'iphonesimulator';
  }

  let buildPath = `build/${scheme}/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/${appName}.app`; // Check wether app file exist, sometimes `-derivedDataPath` option of `xcodebuild` not works as expected.

  if (!_fs().default.existsSync(_path().default.join(buildPath))) {
    return `DerivedData/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/${appName}.app`;
  }

  return buildPath;
}
```

The trick is not to patch this file, but to first setup your xcode configuration correctly `Xcode > Preferences > Locations` (see picture)

[image]

and `Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Advanced`

[image]

Once this is done, you have to cleanup your build folder, otherwise, `react-native-cli` will still assume that xcode is not behaving as expected, which will keep on producing the same error.

`cd ios && rm -rf build`

you can now execute `npx react-native run-ios` and everything should be fine again.

It took me quite some time to figure this out, I think that `react-native-cli` should output more details on what is going on under the hood for people not to be blocked.

Comment: Indeed, I was using similar method to solve my multiple project build path. Instead of setting under preferences, i set under *Workspace Settings* with **custom (relative to workspace)** and path `build/{project_name}/Build/Products`. @shotofcode perhaps you can give above solution a try

Comment: Well, hell. That didn't work. ;-/. I still can't find a working solution.

Comment: Annie Tan's comment above worked for me. Open xCode->File->WorkspaceSettings..

Comment: The solution proposed by @AnnieTan partly works for me. The `/{project_name}/Build/Products` doesn't work out as expected. But when I just enter `build` in the *custom (relative to workspace)* field, it works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to edit a file inside @react-native-community.

If anyone else has the same problem solution is below.

```
File location:
-> file: 
    -> node_modules
        -> @react-native-community
          -> cli-platform-ios
                -> build
                    -> commands
                        -> runIOS
                            -> index.js line 314
```

Change:`DerivedData/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/${appName}.app`

To:`build/Build/Products/${configuration}-${device}/${appName}.app`

```
Cheers.
```

Comment: That may work in the short-term. I don't think that would be a permanent solution. As soon as you wipe your `node_modules` folder, the solution goes with it. At this point, I'll try anything.

Comment: Just checked. The `buildProject()` function has been refactored making this solution no longer viable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: cannot find .app in the Debug-iphonesimulator folder anymore.... Any fixe ?